# Geo Specific Restriction for Data replication on Node

Tags: nodes, consensus, eris-industries, monax

Lets say an Ecosystem is setup with a private Ethereum blockchain or even Monax and it is spread across world wide.

Now there is a possibility that few organizations who want to join the Ecosystem, may not want to get their data replicated in one specific Geo location.

**Questions**
Q1. Is there any feature already available to restrict this data replication replication for specific Geo location.

Q2. Even if we achieve how the consensus will be arrived if all parties are not taking part

Possibly some kind of group if created specific to Geo location who are expected to take part in the consensus. But is such thing supported as of now.

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about geo-location restrictions being a core feature of Hyperledger Burrow, then the answer is no. It is not a current feature; neither is it a planned feature. Burrow is, however, an open source project so you can fork and add that feature on your own.